# Is "open to" followed by infinitive or gerund?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I'd like to use the below sentence as a professional social network profile headline to say that I am looking for employment opportunities. Should I say "run" or "running", and why? Note that I don't use a determinant ("a new project") and that I use capital letters beccause this is a headline.

> Open to **Run** New Project

> Open to **Running** New Project

PS: My translate App uses "running", but I don't know if it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Open to**, meaning "willing to accept or consider", is always followed by a noun or noun phrase (including pronouns).  You can see examples of this in [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=open%20to%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), or in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22open%20to%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdfctqcLoDqYo9ri7kT-FQxLpE4pAQ:1679674486520&ei=dswdZLegH-aq5NoP7PGXgAQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi3s-2I-_T9AhVmFVkFHez4BUA4ChDw0wN6BAgPEBk&biw=1613&bih=808&dpr=1).

So, since *open to* needs a noun after it, what can we do when we want to talk about a verb?  We use the noun form of the verb, the gerund:
I am open to (to manage) -> I am open to **managing**.

Answer (score 2):

This one's easy.

- Jill is open to going on an island holiday on Corfu, but not on The
  Orkneys.
- Fatima is open to managing the project.

The question author has pointed out something based on the expression "I'm open to work" and wonders why it uses 'work' rather than 'working'.

The short answer is that 'work' in this case is the noun, not the verb.

Comment: Work isn't a verb in that case, It's the noun.